# Doxygen: How to enable automated Referenced-By list

Tags: doxygen

when I create a `@page P1` and I `@ref` this page in some other page `P2` then want to have an automatically added list of references on `P1` which gives me a link to `P2`. Is this possible somehow?

I was hoping the `REFERENCED_BY_RELATION` setting would do this but it is not.

Comment: The `REFERENCED_BY_RELATION` is for referencing function / methods / global variables etc. but it is not for pages. The information for the `REFERENCED_BY_RELATION` is taken from the code and not from the documentation sections. Where do you want to have a list of references on P1? Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.9.1. Yes I would like to have the list on P1 and it should show me that this page (P1) is referenced by P2. And I don't want to create this list manually because actually my use case is that I have many pages (describing test functions) that reference many sub-pages (describing files). And when looking on a file description I need to know which test case functions are using them. When doing this manually it would mean a lot of maintenance each time something is changed.

Comment: Probably can accomplish something with a combination of an `ALIASES` setting and using the command `\xreflist`

Comment: Yes I'm already using this. I have a lot of test functions and on each function description I add a list of used testfiles with my @testfile xref which I have added to ALIASES as testfile=\xrefitem my_testfiles "ConfigFile" "". Then it creates me a page where I can see for each testfunction which testfiles it uses. That is already very nice. But what is missing is the oppisite direction. I need to list all functions that reference a testfile on the testfile description.